# Beamer: allowframebreak not working for my outline slide containing both the sections ans subsections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, allowframebreaks

My professor has given me his custom made beamer template for making presentation slides. So, I was preparing slides using his template. However, I have ran into a problem which I am not able to solve. My outline slide contains the name of sections and subsections and it was too large to fit in a single frame. So, I used the command `\allowframebreaks`, but it produced an unpleasant output that can be seen here:

[image]

**I want section 1 and section 2 (along with their respective subsections) on first slide
and section 3 and section 4 (along with their respective subsections) on second slide.**

I am sharing the download link of my [beamer template.](https://github.com/PowerUnlock/Beamer_Template/archive/refs/heads/main.zip)

Please download the zip-folder and compile the file **document.tex** given in it.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Note that generally we do not like to go off site to get example code. Additionally external links have a tendency to rot ove time making your question unusable for others. So please copy relevant parts here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine framebreaks with overlays, they don't play nice together. As you are anyway splitting your toc manually, use overlays and not framebreaks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hyderabad}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \only<1>{\tableofcontents[sections={1-2},currentsection,currentsubsection]}
    \only<2>{\tableofcontents[sections={3-4},currentsection,currentsubsection]}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Overview}
\subsection{Problem formulation for vector recovery}
\subsection{Known result}
\subsection{Abstract of our work}
\section{BCH Codes}
\subsection{An overview of linear codes}
\subsection{Narrow-sense primitive binary BCH codes}
\section{New construction method utilizing the known weight distribution of BCH codes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked.

Comment: @shashankranjan You're welcome!